# Check if a point is in the interior of the convex hull of some other points in high dimensions, and lower-bounding the largest enclosed ball

Tags: linear-programming, computational-geometry, convex-geometry, polytopes, convex-hulls

Given $m$ points $P=\{p_0, p_1, ..., p_m\}$ in high dimensions (e.g. 100), it is known that computing (or even representing) their convex hull $\text{conv}(P)$ is generally intractable due to the exponential dependence on dimensions. In this case, I wonder:

1. Is there an efficient algorithm to check whether some other given point $\tilde{p}$ is an interior point in the convex hull (i.e. there is a small ball centered at $\tilde{p}$ and lies in $\text{conv}(P)$)? I know we can construct a linear programming problem to check if a point lies inside the convex hull, but my question here is to further check if the convex hull has "volume" and if $\tilde{p}$ lies in its interior.
2. Following 1, can we compute or efficiently lower-bounding the largest enclosed (inscribed) ball centered at $\tilde{p}$ and lies in $\text{conv}(P)$?

I'm an amateur in geometry and I appreciate any potential solutions or suggestions. Thank you for your time!

The [same question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381810/check-if-a-point-is-in-the-interior-of-the-convex-hull-of-some-other-points-in-h/) posted on mathoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Does the interior point algorithm finds an ellipsoid as the result? I mean we can define a convex program with being in convex hull of $P_i$s and objective function as the distance between the variable point and $\tilde{p}$. The interior point algorithm on this mathematical program will return an ellipsoid, if possible?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I may not be clear on describing the problem but in question 2 I am looking for the largest inscribed ball within that convex hull. In this sense, to construct the optimization problem we may need exponentially many constraints since the number of faces of the polytope generally has an exponential dependence on dimensions.

And for question 1, the interior point method may work in the relative interior of the convex hull, but I also wonder if we can check if the convex hull really has "volume". Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are seeking for? 
https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a153542.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I took a look from Google cached file, yet it seems that in this paper the polytope is given by linear inequalities. In my problem the inequalities (hyperplanes) needed to represent the polytope may be exponentially many given points in high dimensions, so I guess that way won't work directly. I'll see if the problem can be constructed in some other way.